# Jetty9 multiple listeners

Tags: jetty, embedded-jetty

I am trying to port my Java app which uses Jetty 8 to Jetty 9.
With Jetty8 I was able to instantiate 2 jetty "servers" listening on different ports, however with Jetty9 only the first server will listen to the port.

```
// first server
Server server1 = new Server(); 
// add http + port 80
server1.start();
server1.join(); 

// second server
Server server2 = new Server(); 
// add http + port 8080
server2.start();
server2.join();
```

it seems server2 is never started, do I need to use some kind of threading with Jetty9?

Comment: With root privileges and/or jetty-setuid: http://www.eclipse.org/jetty/documentation/current/setting-port80-access.html

Answer (score 1):

`server1.join()` will block until the server is stopped! So the code for `server2` is never being executed until you stop server1.

Move the `server1.join()` to `server2.join()` (to the end) and it should work as expected:

```java
// first server
Server server1 = new Server(); 
// add http + port 80
server1.start();

// second server
Server server2 = new Server(); 
// add http + port 8080
server2.start();

server1.join(); 
server2.join();
```

Comment: Note that with this rearrangement of the `server.join()` calls, if you stop `server1`, the call to `server1.join()` will complete then the `server2.join()` call will execute and wait for `server2` to be stopped.